# R leaflet package produces blank (grey) map [Ubuntu 14.04]

Tags: javascript, r, leaflet, ubuntu-14.04

I tried out the examplecode from the `leaflet` package doc:

```
devtools::install_github("rstudio/leaflet");library(leaflet)
m <- leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%  # Add default OpenStreetMap map tiles
  addMarkers(lng=174.768, lat=-36.852,
             popup="The birthplace of R")
m  # Print the map
```

but it only produced a **grey, blank map** in the RStudio Viewer, as well as in my Firefox 38.0. Maybe this has something to do with Ubuntu?

Here my sessionInfo:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS

locale:
[1] LC_CTYPE=de_DE.UTF-8 LC_NUMERIC=C  C_TIME=de_DE.UTF-8   
    C_COLLATE=de_DE.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8   
[6] LC_MESSAGES=de_DE.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=de_DE.UTF-8 
 LC_NAME=C  LC_ADDRESS=C     LC_TELEPHONE=C           
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] leaflet_1.0.0.9999 rgdal_0.9-2        sp_1.0-17         

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] Rcpp_0.11.5        magrittr_1.5       devtools_1.7.0
MASS_7.3-41        munsell_0.4.2      colorspace_1.2-6   
lattice_0.20-31   
[8] stringr_0.6.2      httr_0.6.1         plyr_1.8.1  
tools_3.2.1        grid_3.2.1         gtable_0.1.2       
tmltools_0.2.6   [15] yaml_2.1.13        digest_0.6.8        
JSONIO_1.3-0      RColorBrewer_1.1-2 reshape2_1.4.1     
gplot2_1.0.1      htmlwidgets_0.3.2 
[22] bitops_1.0-6       RCurl_1.95-4.5     scales_0.2.5   
proto_0.3-10
```

Comment: Are you getting any console errors? Do you provide the tiles?

Comment: No, no console errors. Tiles were added using `addTiles()`

Comment: I meant: Where are the tiles coming from? Not sure anymore but last time I used leaflet i had to provide an api key to grab openstreetmaps from the internet, so my initial guess was that maybe no map images are downloaded and that's why the map container stays gray?

Comment: Tiles are coming from OSM. The example code works on other computers, I tried it on a Win07.

Answer (score 2):

I get the same thing. Same happens for me when I am work. I think that the corporate IT dept. is blocking certain network traffic.  Try it again at home.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This worked for me, however, what threw me off is that while at work the map rendered in R (not Rstudio)

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue, but there was no proxy issues (I was admin, it was at home etc)
The basemap showed for me in RStudio, but not in html.

The solution is simply reminding leaflet what the basemap is. It defaults to OSM in RStudio output, but then didn't export it with html.

I simply added the tag

```
%>% addProviderTiles(providers$OpenStreetMap) %>%
```

Use

```
names(providers)
```

to see all providers of basemaps.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

Resolved for me by specifying `urlTemplate` parameter in `addTiles()`:

```
library(leaflet)
leaflet() %>% 
  addTiles(urlTemplate = 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png')
```

Comment: Thank you; this is the only solution that worked for me. The Tiles needed an online source and couldn't be passed from RStudio while knitting Rmd to HTML.